# What's the best way to implement automatic type conversion between related types in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm implementing 5 coordinate systems (let's call them A,B,C,D,E), each with its own unique type `Coordinates<System>` holding the coordinates. I want the C++ compiler to correctly transform automatically between coordinates of different systems. The coordinate transformations form a graph: A-B-C-D and C-E. Thus, we need to specify only 8 elementary conversion and the compiler will generate the rest:

```
enum CoordSys { A,B,C,D,E };
template<CoordSys System> struct Coordinates;
template<> struct Coordinates<A> {  // specialisation for system A
   // ...
   operator Coordinates<B>() const; // implements transformation A -> B
};
template<> struct Coordinates<B> {  // specialisation for system B
   // ...
   operator Coordinates<A>() const; // implements transformation B -> A
   operator Coordinates<C>() const; // implements transformation B -> C
};
template<> struct Coordinates<C> {  // specialisation for system C
   // ...
   operator Coordinates<B>() const; // implements transformation C -> B
   operator Coordinates<D>() const; // implements transformation C -> D
   operator Coordinates<E>() const; // implements transformation C -> E
};
template<> struct Coordinates<D> {  // specialisation for system D
   // ...
   operator Coordinates<C>() const; // implements transformation D -> C
};
template<> struct Coordinates<E> {  // specialisation for system E
   // ...
   operator Coordinates<C>() const; // implements transformation E -> C
};
```

The compiler will work out the conversion between coordinates of any two systems, for example

```
double radiusE(Coordinates<E> const&x); // radius is best computed from system E

template<CoordSys Sys> double radius(Coordinates<Sys> const&x)
{ return radiusE(x); }       // implicit type conversion to system E
```

However, the specialisations are tedious, as the `// ...` parts may be lengthy and largely identical (it is still tedious if I inherit from a common base). Ideally, I would want to avoid the specialisations and have just one definition of the class template `Coordinates<>` -- how can I do that? Or is there another useful option?

Comment: It's better to avoid implicit conversions rather than create more of them.

Comment: If you need a specialization for every system, then you shouldn't use a template here.

Comment: I don't think this can work. The compiler only looks for *one* user-defined conversion, and not a sequence of conversions when doing implicit conversions. In your example, the compiler would have to perform two user-defined conversions to convert `Coordinates<A>` to `Coordinates<C>`.

Comment: @Xeo I don't need a specialisation for every system, only the transformations need specialisation.

Comment: "we need to specify only 8 elementary conversion and the compiler will generate the rest" - not really, because a conversion chain can only include one user-defined conversion.

Comment: @BjörnPollex (& Steve Jessop) yes, this seems correct. So this collapses my original idea ;-( I will need to specify all trivial conversion in the chain.

Comment: @Walter: alternatively, you could what Frerich says, with a single class that can represent any of them, use that for public interfaces, and then when you need a particular system, convert to it. You say this will be expensive, but you don't have to use one of the systems as the common type, you could have a class that stores its co-ordinates in whatever system it's constructed from, and lazily converts to the others as they're requested. So you wouldn't convert "back and forth", just forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do the implicit conversion in the constructor instead of as convert-to member functions.

That way you could have a template constructor over your coordinate types, and if you don't need full speed of conversions, you could convert everything to cartesian (or whatever) and then to the special representation:

```
 template<class X>
 class Coordinate {
     template <class Y>
     Coordinate(Coordinate<Y> that) { setFromCartesian(that.toCartesian()); }

     Coordinate<Cartesian> toCartesian() { ... }

     ....
 }
```

Then you can specialize that ctor for those conversions that need the speed of dedicated code, but leave the above version for most other code.

You could also use enable_if and free functions to make sure the constructor fails properly:

```
   Coordinate<A> convert(Coordinate<B> that) { return ... }       

   template<class X, class Y>
   struct ConvertCheck {
        static const bool ok = False;
   };

   template<>
   struct ConvertCheck<A, B> {
        static const bool ok = True
   };

   ..

   template<class X>
   class Coordinate {  
         typedef Coordinate<X> this_type;

         template <class Y>
         Coordinate(Coordinate<Y> that, boost::enable_if(ConvertCheck<X,Y>::ok) { 
             *this = convert<this_type>(that);
         }

         ...
   }
```

Another way would be to define the conversion chains using meta programming and invoke the right sequence (using boost::mpl or sometihng similiar). That would be a nice exercise, which I don't have time to flesh out right now...

Comment: I like that approach. I implemented it using gcc 4.3.2 with options  -std=c++0x -std=gnu++0x and `std::enable_if<>` (from file type_traits), but this failed: it couldn't resolve the required type conversions. However, if I omit the `enable_if` stuff, it works!

Answer (score 2):

How about you go for a simple `Coordinate` type which has some internal representation convertible into all systems (for instance, it stores its data in system `A`) and then have a few methods to translate to specialized types? Something like

```
class Coordinate {
public:
  CoordinateA toSystemA();
  CoordinateB toSystemB();
  // ..
};
```

I'm not even sure why you'd need templates here in the first place. The idea is that instead of chaining conversions, you have a canonical representation which can be converted into specializations (assuming you want to go for specialized types per coordinate system so that your function signatures are more descriptive).

Comment: This is a different design pattern, which is simpler, but (depending on the application) may result in many transformations back and forth, which may be computation intensive.

Answer (score 1):

since you said it is largely identical, my idea is like the following:

```
enum CoordSys { A,B,C,D,E };

template<CoordSys System>
struct Coordinates
{
    template<CoordSys XformSystem>
    operator Coordinates<typename
                         std::enable_if<!std::is_same<System, XformSystem>::value,
                                        XformSystem>::type
                        >() const
    {
        // implementation according to System -> XformSystem
    }
};
```

not tested thought, feel free to edit.

Comment: this was my original design, except for the `enable_if` stuff. I thought I could avoid explicitly giving all the 20 possible transform operations, but this seems not possible ...

Comment: thought: write a simple program to generate the different codes (or transformation parameters) for different coordinate systems. you only need to write 8 of them as you mentioned, then generate the remaining. Finally use your specialization method or the enable_if method. Hope this help.